# Proof by induction that given the recurrence $b_{n+1} = b_n-\frac{b_n^2}{2}$, $\frac{1}{n+1}\leq b_n\leq\frac{2}{n+2}$

Tags: inequality, induction, recurrence-relations, proof-explanation

[image]I need to prove by induction that, given the recurrence $b_{n+1} = b_n-\frac{1}{2} b_n^2$,

$$\frac{1}{n+1} \leq b_n \leq \frac{2}{n+2}.$$

This recurrence comes from another probability problem (in the image attached). I'm completely lost how to prove this inequality. Tried many different approaches, but nothing works, the bounds are not too tight. But if you compute $b_n$ for various values of $n,$ both inequalities always hold. $b_0=1$, $b_1=\frac{1}{2}.$

Would really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Try induction with respect to $n$

Comment: There isn't an image attached.  Also, shouldn't there be an initial value for $b_1?$

Comment: What do we have to prove?

Comment: You **need** to give a first term $b_0$ or $b_1$. Is your result  dependent of the value of this first term... ?

Comment: The keys point, I think, is that $f(x)=x-{x^2\over2}$ is an increasing function on $[0,1]$

Comment: @saulspatz: sorry, turns out I don't yet have enough posts on the website to be allowed to upload images. :(

Comment: If you can post the image somewhere, and include a link to it in your question, someone will edit the question to include the image.

Comment: @saulspatz: ok, I'm now allowed to attach images after all of the great replies to this post from you guys. I've just attached it.

Comment: @Jean Marie: yes, sorry for forgetting to put the value of $b_0$ in the original post. I’ve put it now.

Comment: I'm still working on fixing my erroneous proof and/or finding a different way. Interesting issue...

Comment: I'have found a diiferent way. I am going to rewrite my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are going to work on sequence ($c_n$) defined by

$$c_n:=1-\beta_n.\tag{0}$$

($c_n$) verifies recurrence relationship 
$$c_{n+1}=\tfrac12(c_n^2+1) \ \ \text{with} \ \ c_0=0$$

(easy to check ; see graphical representation below).

**Remarks :**

- The technical interest of using $c_n$ instead of $\beta_n$ is that $c_n$ occurs only once in the RHS of the recurrence relationship (think to the canonical expression for the quadratic of this RHS).
- Recurrence relationship shows that $\forall n, \ c_n\geq 0$ and, by an immediate recurrence, that $c_n \in [0,1]$.
- $c_n$ has a natural interpretation as the probability of the complementary event.

Inequalities to be proved :

$$\forall n, \ \dfrac{1}{n+1} \  \leq \ \beta_n \ \leq \ \dfrac{2}{n+2}$$

become the following ones :

$$\forall n, \ \ 1-\dfrac{2}{n+2}\leq c_n \leq 1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}$$

(observe the reversal of the inequality symbols).
 Said otherwise :

$$\text{To be established :} \ \  \forall n, \  \ \underbrace{ \ \ \dfrac{n}{n+2}\leq c_n \leq \dfrac{n}{n+1}}_{\text{Property} \ (P_n)}\tag{1}$$

Let us prove (1) by recurrence.

- property $(P_0)$ is true.
- General step : $\forall n, \ (P_n) \implies (P_{n+1})$, i.e.,

$$(2a) \ \ \dfrac{n}{n+2}\leq c_n \leq \dfrac{n}{n+1}\ \ \implies \ \ (2b) \ \ \dfrac{n+1}{n+3}\leq c_{n+1} \leq \dfrac{n+1}{n+2}\tag{2}$$

Let us square the three members of (2a) (legal because all of them are positive) ; then add $1$ and divide by $2$ all of them, giving :

$$\dfrac{(n+2)^2+n^2}{2(n+2)^2} \leq c_{n+1} \leq \dfrac{(n+1)^2+n^2}{2(n+1)^2}.$$

It is now easy to see that (2b) will be established if we are able to show that, for all $n$ :

$$\dfrac{(n+2)^2+n^2}{2(n+2)^2} \geq \dfrac{n+1}{n+3} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \dfrac{(n+1)^2+n^2}{2(n+1)^2} \leq \dfrac{n+1}{n+2}.$$

Indeed, the first inequality is reducible to $4 \geq 0$ and the second one to $n \geq 0$, both true...

[image]

*Fig. 1 : Graphical representation of the convergence of sequence $(c_n)$. The points on the curve have coordinates $(c_k,c_{k+1})$.*

**Last remarks :**

- Sequence $(c_n)$ can be found on OEIS site as https://oeis.org/A167424 and http://oeis.org/A076628
  giving interesting connections. (reference found in the following answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/12493)
- Experimental computations show that the lower bound $1/(n+1)$ for $\beta_n$ is not tight at all.

Comment: Do you mean $b_1=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @Sangchul Lee Thanks. You are right, I must begin at index $1$.

Comment: As you see, I have completely re-written my answer. Could you check it (as you have so well done it yesterday, discovering the bugs) ?...

Comment: @Jean Marie: many thanks for doing a second solution and sorry for the delayed reply! I've checked your second solution, can confirm it's correct, and I see no errors. A really nice trick with doing a recurrence for $c_n = 1-\beta_{n}$ instead of taking the original recurrence for $\beta_n$. That has never occurred to me, I've instead kept trying to deduce the desired inequalities from the original recurrence, which was impossible because the resultant bounds were broader than the ones needed... Thank you so much for spending your time and thought on these two proofs. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Andrey Pleasure. Moreover, $c_n$ has a natural interpretation as the probability of the complementary event.

Comment: I just found a strange occurence of sequence $c_n$ : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/237517}

Comment: I have added an interesting connection to OEIS site at the end of my answer.

Comment: @Andrey I have added a graphical "staircase" representation of the convergence of sequence $(c_n).$

Comment: @Jean Marie: thank you! This gives a very nice visual illustration of the convergence of the recurrence!

Comment: @Jean Marie: also I went through the proof again, and found a very minor correction. For the left-hand side of the inequality, I think in the proof the inequality should transform to $4\geq0$ rather than $2\geq0$, not that it really matters though!

Comment: Thanks, Andrey. I fix it.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not necessarily need induction to prove that, here is a quick solution: For the inequality to be true, we must have $b_0 = 1$, which will be assumed hereafter. Then it is easy to check that $0 \leq b_n \leq 1$ for all $n \geq 0$. Moreover, since

$$ \frac{1}{b_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{b_n} + \frac{1}{2-b_n}, $$

it follows that

$$ \frac{1}{b_n} = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2 - b_k}. $$

Together with the bounds of $b_n$, this proves

$$ 1 + \frac{n}{2} \leq \frac{1}{b_n} \leq 1 + n, $$

which then translates to the desired inequality.

---

**Addendum.** It is also easy to check that $b_n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Then by Cesaro-Stolz theorem, we have

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1/b_n}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{b_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{b_n}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2-b_n} = \frac{1}{2}, $$

and so, $b_n \sim \frac{2}{n}$ as $n\to\infty$. Better asymptotic forms can also be extracted by refining this argument.

Comment: [+1] Clever solution ...

Comment: @JeanMarie, Thank you :)

Comment: @SangchulLee: thanks for providing a very clever alternative solution!