Asymptotics of $a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{a_n^2}{2}$
Suppose we have a sequence of the (recursive) form $a_{n+1}=a_n - \frac{a_n^2}{2}$. And $a_0$ is set to be $<1$. Hopefully this sequence goes to zero.
Is there any way to estimate the asymptotic behaviour of $a_n$? Is it $a_n= \mathcal{O}(1/n)$?
What I have tried is that we can rewrite the recursive formula to obtain:
$$a_{n+1}= -\frac{1}{2}(a_n^2-2a_n+1-1)= \frac{-1}{2}(a_n-1)^2 + \frac{1}{2},$$ then subtract 1 on both sides we have:
$$a_{n+1}-1 = \frac{-1}{2}(a_n-1)^2 - \frac{1}{2}.$$
Define $1-a_n$ as $b_n$ we can have
$$b_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}b_n^2 + \frac{1}{2}$$
Further denote $\frac{1}{2}b_n$ as $c_n$, we have $$c_{n+1} = c_n^2 + \frac{1}{4}.$$

Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3338103/42969

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/convergence-of-sqrtnx-n-where-x-n1-sinx-n with a general treatment of $a_{n+1}=a_n+ca_n^d+...$, $d\ge 1$ and  topics linked from there.

You loosely compare this with the class of Bernoulli equations to find a suitable variable change. Here $u_n=\frac1{a_n}$. Then use series expansion using that $a_n$ is very small for large $n$:
$$
u_{n+1}=u_n\left(1-\frac{a_n}2\right)^{-1}=u_n\left(1+\frac{a_n}2+\frac{a_n^2}4+...\right)=u_n+\frac12+O(a_n)
$$
so that asymptotically $u_n\asymp \frac n2$ and thus $a_n\asymp\frac2n$.
